# Laravel ajax status error like - "Status Code: 403 in Laravel ajax post"

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-403

there is an issue with my ajax, I have passed the post method but local its work fine but in live server  there is any problem like : Status Code: 403,
my function look like below

```
  // validate and save posted data
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $rules = array(
            'content' => 'required',
        );

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $template->updateContent($request->content);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
        ]);
    }
```

in localhost function goes to "$request->isMethod('post')", but when I run the same function in live server then condition is not matched and return 403 error on ajax status

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, or sending an POST, PUT or PATCH request you may encounter a Laravel error page saying: 403 | THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED. **As the error says, this means the user isn't authorized to make the request.**

Comment: how to fix this ?

Comment: ADD ONE OFF THIS ON AJAX CALL

`//headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic bWFkaHNvbWUxMjM='},`

or 
`
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },
`

Comment: I think we should suggest one solution in your post.